# Create USB Recovery Drive For Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I recently upgraded my ASUS G75VW from Windows 7 to Windows 10. Now I am trying to create a recovery drive with the system files. I was following the tutorial [here](https://www.winhelp.us/create-a-recovery-drive-in-windows-8.html). But I get an error message saying "A problem occurred while creating the recovery drive".

So I searched the internet, and ran `sfc /scannow,` but it was unable to fix the files. So I opened the error log, and posted it [here](http://pastebin.com/Vnjb0Jvv).

I appreciate it if someone could help me please. Thank you.

Comment: im confused. Are you just trying to copy your entire hard drive to a flash drive?

Comment: @GmanSmith I apologize for not clarifying this. I don't think I'm trying to back my entire hard drive to my flash drive. But in the wizard where I create the recovery drive, there's an option to "Back up system files to the recovery drive". The tutorial at https://www.winhelp.us/create-a-recovery-drive-in-windows-8.html says to tick it.

Comment: This is how microsoft says to do it http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-usb-recovery-drive

Comment: Thanks for the link, but when I click next with the **Copy the recovery partition from the PC to the recovery drive** check box selected, I get an error saying "A problem occurred while creating the recovery drive"

Comment: None of these answers are helpful. I have the same problem, and of course to try to create this recovery disc I have followed those precise instructions, but like the OP and others I receive that same error message: "A problem occurred while creating the recovery drive". The only other information I can add is that this is not an upgrade from an earlier version of Windows, but a brand new PC that came with Windows 10 already installed. David

Answer (score 2):

Stop and Disable the following 3 services (related with Microsoft Word/Excel Starter 2010) and reboot. I could create a recovery drive with system files after that.
 
- sftlist Application Virtualization Client
- cvhsvc Client Virtualization Handler
- sftvsa Application Virtualization Service Agent
I had noticed that RecoveryDrive.exe triggers a VSS error message in the event log, which helped me to remember that I had had interferences between Application Virtualization and Volume Shadow Copies before.

Answer (score 0):

#### Create USB Recovery Drive For Windows 10

The instructions for Windows 10 are different to Windows 8, there is no mention of a "Copy the recovery partition from the PC to the recovery drive" check box.

> **Applies to Windows 10**
>
> A recovery drive can help you troubleshoot and fix problems with your
>   PC, even if it won’t start. To create one, all you need is a USB
>   drive.
>
> 1. From the taskbar, search for Create a recovery drive and then select it. You might be asked to enter an admin password or confirm
>      your choice.
> 2. When the tool opens, make sure Back up system files to the recovery drive is selected and then select Next.
> 3. Connect a USB drive to your PC, select it, and then select Next > Create. A lot of files need to be copied to the recovery drive, so this might take a while.
> 4. When it’s done, you might see a Delete the recovery partition from your PC link on the final screen. If you want to free up drive
>      space on your PC, select the link and then select Delete. If not,
>      select Finish.

Source [Create a recovery drive](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/create-a-recovery-drive)

Comment: This answer isn't helpful. I have the problem myself and how to create a recovery drive is not the issue. The problem is that shortly after clicking next on the create recovery drive dialog a message simply stating "A problem occurred while creating the recovery drive" appears before I'm even asked to select a USB drive. This happens whether I check the option to backup system files or not. SFC found problems it couldn't fix. DISM got me past that but I still get the same error. Can't find any indication of why it fails.

Comment: @SteveCrane Please create a new question regarding your problem, as it is different to the issue the OP had in his question.

Comment: I disagree that the problem is different but will post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I had experienced this problem as well.  For me, doing a full (rather than fast) format of the USB stick before running RecoveryDrive.exe solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If for any reason, the Microsoft tools don't work to create a USB drive, you can create it manually:

1. **Download the Windows 10 ISO** matching your version

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench

The Microsoft support frontpage detects your current configuration and may redirect you to the USB drive page instead. So it's better to follow the provided link be sure to get the `.iso` image file.

2. **Build a bootable USB disk manually**

Just download a freeware for this, such as [IsoToUsb](http://www.isotousb.com/). You'll need an empty USB disk, 8GB at least.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. He is trying to create a recovery drive having already installed Windows 10.

Comment: I propose an alternative option since it does not work from Windows 10...